# TypeScript with system.js module running in node error

Tags: typescript

I would like to use the system.js module manager with TypeScript.
My plan is to run typescript in node

The problem is that, if i mark my Main.js (generated from Main.ts) file as the entry point, it will crash with this error:

ReferenceError: System is not defined

And it's normal, because my generated code start like this:
System.register(["./Apple"], function(exports_1) {

And for sure, there is no System class in node by default.
So how to make typescript or node to load the system.js module?

I can create an extra js file to load it with require, but i'm looking for a native solution inside typescript

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You should tell the compiler to export your modules into commonjs and not systemjs. Node is using commonjs as its native module system.

Comment: But i think system.js support node according to system.js documentation:

NodeJS
To load modules in NodeJS, install SystemJS with:
`npm install systemjs`

We can then load modules equivalently to in the browser:

`var System = require('systemjs');

System.transpiler = 'traceur';

// loads './app.js' from the current directory
System.import('./app').then(function(m) {
  console.log(m);
});`
If using TypeScript, set `global.ts = require('typescript')` before importing to ensure it is loaded correctly.

Comment: This is a way to load node modules into the browser, just like browserify... this will not help you load modules in node. NodeJS is already capable of loading modules, they are using commonjs. and TypeScript can transpile the modules into commonjs.

Comment: I do not agree with you. You can use system.js in node enviroment too, and i was successfully managed it. You just have to load it:
require("systemjs")
and after you can use all the features of systemjs. 

My problem is that for this i need to add an extra init.js file to my project, but this way for some reason i cannot debug my typescript sources (when i use the normal commonjs system it works)

Comment: Why do you insist on using systemjs if commonjs works for you?

Comment: Just to add to the answer, here is how it should be done if you're using `tsconfig.json`: inside `compilerOptions` section, replace `"module": "system"` with `"module": "commonjs"`. This way, when running `tsc`, it'll compile it to `require` instead of `System.register`. Also, If you use TypeScript for the client side as well, you may get an error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`, in this case you should remove  the `“format: ‘register’ “` from your System.Config.

Answer (score 2):

I might not understand correctly, but have you tried to follow the `node.js` section on `system.js` GitHub Readme (https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)?

`$ npm install systemjs`

then:

```
var System = require('systemjs');

// loads './app.js' from the current directory
System.import('./app').then(function(m) {
  console.log(m);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using tsconfig file?
You have add the module:'system'
I was facing a similar problem, this fixed it. Also ensure that the system.src.js is at top of the scripts.